# How to join multiple fields data from two different tables in SQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using this query to join data from two different tables. Invoice table holding data, with stock code and supplier code. Please check my query point out my error in query.
inv_code field holding stock code and supplier code. My second table is 
`cb_chart_temp` having `acc_code`, and `acc_name`;

```
SELECT 
      `invoice`.`inv_code`, 
      `cb_chart_temp.acc_name`, 
      `invoice.sup_id`,
      `cb_chart_temp`.`acc_name` 
FROM 
      `invoice`, 
      `cb_chart_temp` 
WHERE 
      inv_no LIKE 'PI%' 
      invoice.inv_code=cb_chart_temp.acc_code 
      AND invoice.sup_id=cb_chart_temp.acc_code
```

My result should look like this!

```
inv_code    acc_name      sup_id       sup_name
ST-00001    Stock Name    SUP-00001    Supplier Name
```

Comment: Does it display an error, or just not expected output?

Comment: `inv_no LIKE 'PI%' and invoice.inv_code=cb_chart_temp.acc_code`.

Comment: please explain the meaning of each of the code fields.

Answer (score 0):

It misses an AND, as already pointed out by @Lion, plus it is doubtful that the join of keys is correct. As you have it, inv_code, acc_code, and sup_id all belong to the same domain, i.e., all of them are, e.g., invoice codes.